# Concatenate multiple fasta files into individual files per unique entry

Tags: genome, bash

I have several splitted fasta files like this:

```
TK273759.fastaaa
TK273759.fastaab
TK273759.fastaac
TK273759.fastaad
TK273759.fastaae
```

I want to concatenate these fasta files into one file like this:

```
TK273759.fasta
```

What command should I use to make this happen? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try searching online before asking for help. A simple `cat` will do the trick here:

```
cat TK273759.fasta[a-z][a-z] > TK273759.fasta
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please accept the answer to provide closure to the post.